# Запись одного или нескольких элементов с приоритетом в MySQL

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Нужно реализовать на сайте выбор голосовых кодеков с приоритетами.

[Фотопример](http://uaimage.com/image/c4bb8995)

**Конфиг кодеков должен быть в виде списка выбранных пользователем не повторяющихся кодеков с предпочитаемым приоритетом их следования.  Количество выбранных кодеков может быть меньше за количество существующих!**

Возникает вопрос правильного проектирования таблиц БД, записи и извлечения данных.
Пока додумался создать две таблицы Codecs и CodecConfig.

Структура таблицы `Codecs`:

```
codec_id (первичный ключ)  
codec_name (название кодека)
```

Структура таблицы `CodecConfig`:

```
config_id (первичный ключ)    
codec1_id (кодек с приоритетом 1, внешний ключ на Codecs.codec_id)  
codec2_id (кодек с приоритетом 2, внешний ключ на Codecs.codec_id)  
codec3_id (кодек с приоритетом 3, внешний ключ на Codecs.codec_id)  
codec4_id (кодек с приоритетом 4, внешний ключ на Codecs.codec_id)  
codec5_id (кодек с приоритетом 5, внешний ключ на Codecs.codec_id)
```

Может можно сделать иначе более правильно?

Comment: А чем вам ваш собственный вариант неугодил? Хотя логичнее было бы структура для CodecConfig:
config_id | codec_id | prioritet_id.

Comment: С такой структурой config_id ничего не скажет, он ссылается на один кодек с одним приоритетом :)

Answer (score 1):

А что, нельзя просто добавить в таблицу Codecs поле codec_priority?

Comment: Codecs описывает только все ид кодеков и их описания. Мне нужен на выходе именно конфиг выбранных кодеков с их приоритетами. Кодеков может быть 5 а пользователь укажет 3 предпочитаемых.

Comment: Ну тогда надо делать вторую таблицу так:

config_id
codec_id
codec_priority
user_id

и добавлять / удалаять строки, согласно выбору пользователя

Comment: CodecConfig: user_id | config_id | codec_id | codec_priority  
Больше склоняюсь к такой реализации, спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так было бы лучше:

```
CodecConfig: config_id | codec_id | prioritet_id.
```

Comment: Это связи в таблицах называется, очень полезная вещь!

Comment: Про связи я чуток знаю.
Хорошо, допустим возьмем  
CodecConfig: config_id | codec_id | prioritet_id
В такой таблице каждая новая запись будет увеличивать/изменять config_id!

Comment: Мне нужно получить весь конфиг зня id конфига, или реализовать иначе.

Comment: Я честно говоря не знаю что вы конкретно задумали, в моем понимании у вас есть какие-то кодеки, у которых разные конфиги (в зависимости от ситуации), в таком случае храниться таблица с именем кодека и его ид и 2-ая таблица уже с самими конфигами.

Comment: Конфиг кодеков должен быть в виде списка выбранных пользователем не повторяющихся кодеков с предпочитаемым приоритетом их следования.  
Вот примерно так :)

Comment: Может дей-но добавить в **Codecs** поле `Code_Priority` и сделать правильную выборку и не мучиться с двумя таблицами и связями?